# Access all content from a post in Django

Tags: python, django

I apologize in advance if the question is poorly written. tried my best to explain my problem as good as i could :). Thanks for helping!

I have currently made a django web server.
i am trying to access all the content from all my different posts and display them by eachother within "ul" and "li" HTML tags.

I am currently only able to display the Main Posts title, and not the rest of the content.

The result i am currently getting is this.

```
My Book List:

* The Hunger Games
```

and the result i am wanting to get is this.

```
My Book List:
* Title: The hunger games
* Author: Suzanne Collins
* Publisher: Scholastic Press
* Published: 2008-09-14
```

I've tried multiple solutions to try and make it work. But i cant find any solution on youtube or any related social media website, so i resorted to here.

*models.py file*

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pulished = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

*Views.py file*

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Books

# Create your views here.
def book_list(request):
    books = Books.objects.all()
    context = {
        'book_list':books
    }
    return render(request, "book_list.html", context)
```

*book_list.html (TEMPLATE FILE)*

```html
<h1>My Book List</h1>

<ul>
    {% for list in book_list %}
        <li>{{list}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

*library/urls.py   (APP)*

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import book_list

urlpatterns = [
    path('', book_list)
]
```

*bookstore/urls.py    (PROJECT)*

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from library import views

urlpatterns = [

   path('', views.book_list),
   path('books/', include('library.urls')),
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

And here is a link to a imgur picture off how my file structure looks like, so you can have some context to what is what.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVlBk.jpg

Comment: Try to add `<li>{{ list.author }}</li>` in the template under the first `<li>` tag. The first one shows the `__str__` method of your model. Try to call the other attributes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this in your book_list.html:

```
<h1>My Book List</h1>

<ul>
    {% for book in book_list %}
        <li>Title: {{book.title}}</li>
        <li>Author: {{book.author}}</li>
        <li>Publisher: {{book.publisher}}</li>
        <li>Published: {{book.pulished}}</li> <!-- The Spell Is Wrong. 'b' is missing ;) -->
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```